# Access options are not permitted for this account type. The options argument must be nil.;

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, crash

I'm looking at my crash logs and i could see this crash:

> Access options are not permitted for this account type. The options argument must be nil.

it's my first time to encounter such crash so i don't exactly know what's happening. I did some research about it and found out that it's caused by Facebook SDK. However, i'm not really sure how it happens or what can i do to fix/handle it.

Is there a way to fix/handle this kind of crash?

Comment: Can you post some code from where the crash is occurring?

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320624/nsinvalidargumentexception-thrown-from-acaccountstore-when-calling-fbsession-op

i don't exactly know where it's happening because i just saw it in the crash logs we've collected. But the link above says it happens in  [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions...]

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @vburojevic sorry for the very late reply. I wasn't able to solve it. We just ignore the crash.