# Swift: Exception when requesting access to Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift3, ios10

After updating to XCode 8, Swift 3, and iOS 10, I've begun to get the following error when requesting permission to access Facebook accounts:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Access options are not
>   permitted for this account type. The options argument must be nil.'

I've found three mentions of this error on SO:

1. [Access options are not permitted for this account type. The options argument must be nil.;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453164/access-options-are-not-permitted-for-this-account-type-the-options-argument-mus)
2. [Facebook SDK login crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732342/facebook-sdk-login-crash)
3. [NSInvalidArgumentException thrown from ACAccountStore when calling [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions...] on iOS 6.0 and iOS 6.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320624/nsinvalidargumentexception-thrown-from-acaccountstore-when-calling-fbsession-op)

The first two have no answers; the last suggests checking that the value returned from [`accountType(withAccountTypeIdentifier ...)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/accounts/acaccountstore/1493967-accounttype) isn't `nil`, which I was already doing.

As mentioned elsewhere, this error is inconsistent with the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/accounts/acaccountstore/1493964-requestaccesstoaccounts), which states that Facebook requires an options dictionary.

Here is a small example which reproduces the problem and makes a big show of error checking everything I could think to error check:

```
import UIKit
import Social
import Accounts

class DVSocialTestViewController: UIViewController {

    let localURL =  URL(string: "fb://")
    let serviceType = SLServiceTypeFacebook
    let accountID = ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook
    var accountType: ACAccountType? {
        return ACAccountStore().accountType(withAccountTypeIdentifier: self.accountID)
    }
    var accounts: [Any]? {
        guard let ac = self.accountType else { return nil }
        return ACAccountStore().accounts(with: ac)
    }
    static let appID = "MyAppID"
    let basicOptions =
        [ACFacebookAppIdKey: DVSocialTestViewController.appID,
         ACFacebookPermissionsKey: ["basic_info"],
         ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends] as [AnyHashable: Any]
    let publishOptions =
        [ACFacebookAppIdKey:DVSocialTestViewController.appID,
         ACFacebookPermissionsKey:["publish_actions"],
         ACFacebookAudienceKey:ACFacebookAudienceFriends] as [AnyHashable: Any]

    var applicationIsInstalled: Bool {
        guard let url = self.localURL else {
            return false
        }
        return UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
    }

    var serviceIsAvailable: Bool {
        return SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: self.serviceType)
    }

    var userIsLoggedIn: Bool {
        guard let ac = self.accounts, ac.count > 0 else {
            NSLog("\(self.accounts)")
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    func requestPermissionsForAccountType(_ type: ACAccountType) {

        ACAccountStore().requestAccessToAccounts(with: type, options: self.basicOptions) {
            (success: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if !success {
                NSLog("\(error)")
                return
            }

            ACAccountStore().requestAccessToAccounts(with: type, options: self.publishOptions) {
                (success: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in
                if !success {
                    NSLog("\(error)")
                    return
                }
            }

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard self.applicationIsInstalled else {
            NSLog("FB Application is not installed.")
            return
        }

        guard self.serviceIsAvailable else {
            NSLog("FB Service is unavailable.")
            return
        }

        guard self.userIsLoggedIn else {
            NSLog("User is not logged into FB.")
            return
        }

        guard let AT = self.accountType else {
            NSLog("No accounts.")
            return
        }

        self.requestPermissionsForAccountType(AT)

    }
}
```

Has anyone run into this?  Any suggestions about what I'm missing?

**Edit:**

There are few reasons why I feel my question is different from the proposed duplicate.

1. I'm not using the Facebook SDK.
2. This is not a "rare case"--it consistently happens with this example every time I run it.
3. This specifically began happening upon updating to XCode 8, Swift 3, and iOS 10 from the preceding versions.
4. As stated above, the only answer to the other question (which I admit is not accepted) does *not* solve my problem.
5. I've provided a complete, minimal example, which the other question does not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSInvalidArgumentException thrown from ACAccountStore when calling \[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions...\] on iOS 6.0 and iOS 6.0.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320624/nsinvalidargumentexception-thrown-from-acaccountstore-when-calling-fbsession-op)

Comment: @iYoung please see edit.