# Facebook SDK login crash

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, crash

Facebook login sometimes crashes.
I am using the latest version of SDK.

On crashlytics I get:

> FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter
>   requestAccessToFacebookAccountStore:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:appID:session:handler:]
>   Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
>
> Access options are not permitted for this account type. The options
>   argument must be nil.

This is the code:

```
- (void)facebookOpenSession
{
    [SVProgressHUD show];
    FBSession* sess = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public_profile"]];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:sess];
    [sess openWithBehavior:(FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent) completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        [self facebookSessionStateChanged:session state:status error:error];
    }];
}
```

I've tried setting nil for permissions as well, but crash occurs sometimes as well.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320624/nsinvalidargumentexception-thrown-from-acaccountstore-when-calling-fbsession-op

Comment: I saw it, but there is no solution